# How do I give a delay in user input to a Textbox in a dash app?

Tags: python, data-visualization, dashboard, plotly-dash

I am learning to build a simple dash app. It has a textbox for user input, depending on which it will draw a graph.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.Div(children='User input:'),
    dcc.Input(id='input', value='', type='text'),
    html.Div(id='output-graph'),
])

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='output-graph', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='input', component_property='value')]
)
def update_value(input_data):
    return dcc.Graph(
    ### Do something ###
    )
```

The problem is, since dash uses react in the background, it keeps throwing errors in the console whenever the input is being entered until it reaches a valid input. For example, if I am plotting stock prices for a stock symbol (say, AAPL), it throws an error after typing each of the letters until typing all 4 valid letters.

I would like to add a delay of, say, 1 sec after the user inputs the last character before the app tries to read the input. How do I do that? I have been searching online about this, but can't find anything.

Also, if the input after the 1-sec delay is an invalid input (like, AAPF instead of AAPL, for instance), it should return something like, `Wrong input, please enter again.`

Comment: I played around with this trying to get something working with asyncio, but to no avail. If I had more time I'd try to get something going with `dcc.Interval`, but would have to give it some more thought. This might help getting asyncio working https://github.com/ned2/dash/blob/support-quart/dash/async.py

Comment: did you tried to use time.sleep(t) ? just before the update_value

Answer (score 7):

Old question, but I came across it while searching for the same thing. I subsequently found on the plotly forums that the `debounce` keyword parameter was added to the dash core components (as of version 0.35.0.). If `debounce` is `True`, then the contents of the input will not be communicated until the user presses enter or clicks out of the box.

For example:

```
dcc.Input(
    id='user-input',
    type='number',
    value=30,            
    style={'fontSize':28},
    debounce = True
),
```

Comment: Cool. I solved the issue by using an if-else. If the input is empty, then `dash.no_update()`, else `code`.

Comment: In case someone is looking for a similar solution but with `dcc.TextArea`, try using `n_blur` as an `Input` and `value` as `State`. Source: https://community.plotly.com/t/debounce-dcc-textarea/29471/2